# RadComboBox autocomplete list show WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, radcombobox

I'm using `RadComboBox` in my `WPF` application. I have a list of values which are sorted in ascending order.

When i type in a letter for eg:'A', the dropdown shows me the list of values starting with 'A' where the first value is shown in the top of the listed values. Now when i type 'H' it shows me the values where the first value is shown in the bottom.

Now what i need is, whatever i type the values should be listed and the first value should be on top followed by other values.

//XAML code:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox Height="23" IsEditable="True" Name="cmbColor" SelectAllTextEvent="GotFocus" ItemsSource="{Binding ColorList, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValuePath="Id" DisplayMemberPath="Descr" IsReadOnly="True" SelectedValue="{Binding Selected.ColorId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8" </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Pics:

In my first instance when i type 'A'.

[image: When typing A the first value comes in top]

After i delete 'A' and type 'H'.

[image: When i tpye H the first value comes at the bottom]

**I have some values for 'H' after this.**

My first instance when i type 'G'

[image: Typing G in first instance]

Why the second typing word isn't showing at the top?

Is there anywhere i'm wrong? Or is it a default functionality?

**FYI,**

For the first instance after i type 'A' i click the dropdown button to show the values whereas for the second letter 'H' or 'G' i don't. It get filters automatically and showing in the bottom.

Kindly help.

Comment: some pictures will help..

Comment: @Muds: Added. Kindly look into this.

Comment: in your first instance instead of 'A' type 'G' and show us what happens, scroll will find the first instance of item starting with alphabet you type and bring that in view not necessarily on top..